# w3m website dump without line break

Tags: files, terminal, w3m

I am not a native english speaker, if any grammatical mistakes please forgive me

every one says books are best friend and remove ignorance, so I got a online library but my english is not good, so i decided that download the text of book and translate it ino my native language with google translate cli.

https://kpu.pressbooks.pub/political-ideologies/front-matter/introduction/

so i install w3m cli web browser and visit the above said website with w3m cli web browser, Here the output is without line breaks.
w3m

but when I store the output of this website it into file the ,there is line breakage

the commands are

1. w3m  >file.txt
   or
2. w3m -dump < website> > file.txt
   after investigating, i found that the coloumn size of each row is around 80.
   the terminal column size 80.
   So in short the line breakage text converted into 1 continuous paragrach.
   so suggest me a solution

thanks in advance

Comment: Better add sample input and expected output

Answer (score 0):

from `man w3m`:

> ```
>    -cols num
>           with  stdout  as  destination;  HTML is rendered to lines of num
>           characters
> ```